# Automate file upload In Safari (WebDriver.IO)

Tags: selenium, safari, webdriver, webdriver-io

Is it possible to automate file uploads in Safari?

The following works for IE, Firefox, Chrome:

```
    let path = 'C:\\test\\image2.png';
    browser.addValue('[name="file_upload"], path);
    $("input[name='http_submit']").click();
```

However on Safari the input value does not change

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .chooseFile() method?

```
browser.chooseFile(selector,localPath);
```

In your example:

```
let path = 'C:\\test\\image2.png';
browser.chooseFile('[name="file_upload"], path);
$("input[name='http_submit']").click();
```